# Why cant i login with the username and password that i created in my data.sql file. it isnt creating any new user from my user table in data.sql file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

This is my SecurityConfiguration file
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration   {

```
@Autowired
private DataSource datasource;

@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(H2)
            .addScript(JdbcDaoImpl.DEFAULT_USER_SCHEMA_DDL_LOCATION)
            .build();
}


protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(datasource).passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
}

public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    return http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER") // User
                    .requestMatchers("/admin","/user" ).hasRole("ADMIN") // Combined rule for admin access
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()) // Authentication for remaining requests
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .build();
}
```

}

This is my data.sql file INSERT INTO users(username, password,enabled)
values('user','pass',true);

INSERT INTO users(username, password,enabled)
values('admin','pass',true);

INSERT INTO authorities(username,authority)
values('user','ROLE_USER');

INSERT INTO authorities(username,authority)
values('admin','ROLE_ADMIN');

This is my schema
create table users(
username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key,
password varchar_ignorecase(500) not null,
enabled boolean not null
);

create table authorities (
username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
authority varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
constraint fk_authorities_users foreign key(username) references users(username)
);
create unique index ix_auth_username on authorities (username,authority);

i am new to this can anyone please help me with this

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot, ditch the `dataSource` bean (as that overrides parts of the auto configuration). and add the script as a `spring.sql.init.schema` script. Next your `configure` method doesn't do anything for newer Spring Securit versions. You only need to define a bean that returns the `NoOpPasswordEncoder` or ditch that all together and use the default encoder and simply prefix yhour password with `{noop}` so Sprnig Security will use the correct one automatically.